# Recovering a 6 drive RAID 5 array using two disks - unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member' with mdadm

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

Hello askubuntu forums,

I'm trying to recover data from a 6 drive NAS set up.  I've tried using mdadm to examine, configure, and mount some drives from this array, but nothing is working.  I've got two of the drives plugged into an USB drive mount.

I can see what partition has data using fdisk.  Anytime I've tried to mount anything though it will either tell me "Unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'" or tell me that the drive is already active.  Been trying to do this all day and I'm hoping someone here can help me out.  Thanks in advance.

```
root@jake-ThinkPad-W541:/home/test# mdadm --query /dev/sdc8
/dev/sdc8: is not an md array
/dev/sdc8: device 1 in 6 device undetected raid5 /dev/md/8.  Use mdadm --examine for more detail.
root@jake-ThinkPad-W541:/home/test# mdadm --examine /dev/sdc8
/dev/sdc8:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 647bf344:1fa055b2:250192e1:f58cf57e
           Name : vg:8
  Creation Time : Wed Apr  1 22:54:11 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 6

 Avail Dev Size : 9749841648 (4649.09 GiB 4991.92 GB)
     Array Size : 24374602240 (23245.43 GiB 24959.59 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 9749840896 (4649.09 GiB 4991.92 GB)
   Super Offset : 9749841904 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=1008 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 1f16d5b6:b82ce930:c52f61f7:df644373

    Update Time : Tue Jun  4 00:52:09 2019
       Checksum : c6070a4 - correct
         Events : 201

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

> cat /proc/mdstat

```
    test@jake-ThinkPad-W541:~$ cat /proc/mdstat

    Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 

    md4 : inactive sdc4[0](S) sdb4[1](S)
  3145704 blocks super 1.0


    md6 : inactive sdc6[0](S) sdb6[1](S)
  2097128 blocks super 1.0


    md7 : inactive sdc7[0](S) sdb7[1](S)
  8388584 blocks super 1.0


    md8 : inactive sdc8[0](S) sdb8[1](S)
  9749841648 blocks super 1.0


    md5 : inactive sdc5[0](S) sdb5[1](S)
  3145704 blocks super 1.0


    unused devices: <none>
```

> sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md8

```
    /dev/md8:
               Version : 1.0
            Raid Level : raid0
         Total Devices : 2
           Persistence : Superblock is persistent

                 State : inactive
       Working Devices : 2

                  Name : vg:8
                  UUID : 647bf344:1fa055b2:250192e1:f58cf57e
                Events : 201

        Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

           -       8       40        -        /dev/sdc8
           -       8       24        -        /dev/sdb8
```

Comment: What does `cat /proc/mdstat` say? Also it says `/dev/sdc8: device 1 in 6 device undetected raid5 /dev/md/8` so try `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md8`

Comment: root@jake-ThinkPad-W541:/media# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md7 : inactive sdb7[0](S) sdc7[1](S)
      8388584 blocks super 1.0
       
md5 : inactive sdb5[0](S) sdc5[1](S)
      3145704 blocks super 1.0
       
md6 : inactive sdb6[0](S) sdc6[1](S)
      2097128 blocks super 1.0
       
md4 : inactive sdc4[1](S) sdb4[0](S)
      3145704 blocks super 1.0
       
md8 : inactive sdb8[0](S) sdc8[1](S)
      9749841648 blocks super 1.0
       
unused devices: <none>


**It looks like it's inactive**

Comment: root@jake-ThinkPad-W541:/media# sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md8
/dev/md8:
           Version : 1.0
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice


**Forgive me but I don't know how to format these comments for easier readability.**

Comment: I would add the output of the the two commands to your question as they are relevant. They will be formatted much better when part of the question.

Comment: I've updated the main post here.  Hopefully someone can help out eh.  Thank you

Comment: Bumping post in hopes for restoration.